# How to change dynamically frame size on mouse over

Tags: javascript, html, frame

Can you tell me how we can change a frame size on mouse over?

eg:

```
<html>
<frameset rows="70%,30%">
<frame src="page1.htm">
<frame src="page2.htm">
</frameset>
</html>
```

On mouse over it should become like this:

```
<frameset rows="40%,60%">
```

And also is there any way we can do like this?

```
 <frameset rows="40%,60%"> ---> <frameset rows="70%,30%">  ---> <frameset rows="40%,60%">
 (after loading webpage;        (after 5 seconds)               (on mouse over)
     for 5 seconds)
```

Comment: Do you want that `onmouseout` -> `<frameset rows="70%,30%">` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var already=false;
var frameset;
window.onload=function(){frameset=document.getElementById("foo");};
setTimeout(modify,5000);
function modify()
{
    already=true;
    frameset.setAttribute("rows","70%,30%");
}
function big()
{
    if(already)frameset.setAttribute("rows","70%,30%");
}
function small()
{
    if(already)frameset.setAttribute("rows","40%,60%");
}
</script>
</head>
<frameset rows="40%,60%" id="foo" >
<frame src="page1.htm">
<frame src="page2.htm" onmouseover="small();" onmouseout="big();">
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear friend, there is some problem with the script its now working; and i forgot to tell something also;i just want this event to happen when i mouseover  the bottom frame only..is it possible

Comment: @t3st For the onmouseover only on the bottom frame, look my edit.

Comment: still not working..this is the code <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var already=false;
var frameset=document.getElementById("foo");
setTimeout(modify,5000);
function modify()
{
    already=true;
    frameset.setAttribute("rows","70%,30%");
}
function big()
{
    if(already)frameset.setAttribute("rows","70%,30%");
}
function small()
{
    if(already)frameset.setAttribute("rows","40%,60%");
}
</script>
</head>
<frameset rows="40%,60%" id="foo" >
<frame src="page1.htm">
<frame src="page2.htm" onmouseover="small();" onmouseout="big();">
</frameset>
</html>

Comment: @t3st Wow! I finally understood the problem (I wasn't familiar with `<frameset>`). The thing is that the frameset replaces the body. So you must put the script in `page1.htm` or `page2.htm` or in the head. I'm editting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQUERY to change frame Size. there is a effect Animation already defined in it.
Its very easy to do with it.