# i need a way to increase the size of a frame on hover event,

Tags: html, css

I have 3 frames on my web page, I need a way to increase the size of the frame on hover event, how do I do that??
here's my code:

```
<html>
<style ="text/css"> </style>
 <frameset cols="33.3%,33.3%,33.3%">
 <frame src="enter.html"> <frame src="prod.html">
 <frame src="game.html"> </frameset>
```

Comment: <html>
<style ="text/css">
</style>
<frameset cols="33.3%,33.3%,33.3%">
<frame src="enter.html">
<frame src="prod.html"> 
<frame src="game.html">
</frameset>

Comment: Just FYI.. Frameset is not Supported in HTML5..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271764/how-to-change-dynamically-frame-size-on-mouse-over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this:

HTML

```
<frameset id="1" cols="33.3%,33.3%,*">
  <frame src="page1.html" onmouseover="big()" onmouseout="small()"></frame>
  <frame src="page2.html" onmouseover="big()" onmouseout="small()"></frame>
  <frame src="page3.html" onmouseover="big()" onmouseout="small()"></frame>
</frameset>
```

Javascript for page1

```
var e = document.getElementById("myframeset");
function big(){
e.setAttribute("cols","60%,20%,*")
}
function small(){
e.setAttribute("cols","33.3%,33.3%,*")
}
```

Note: You would not place the javascript code in the page containing frameset. The javascript code should be placed in page1, page2 and page3 correspondingly.

Comment: I tried it with my code but it's not working. Check this https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FE2C9022D00ED02E%21954

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/9vsr0ybx/

```
iframe{
width:400px;
height:400px;
}

iframe:hover{
width:500px;
height:500px;
}
```

Comment: can i do it with frame rather than i frame?

Comment: @ParthVerma Can you show a working fiddle with frames?

Comment: @ParthVerma use iframes it is more better

Comment: @ParthVerma Not on jsfiddle?  you mean its not working?